# PPT file corrupt - One drive REST API

Tags: php, laravel-5, guzzle, onedrive

Not sure why but for reasons when I uploaded PPT or PPTX files using below code that file somehow get corrupted. When I try viewing that file in one drive it shows me error **"Sorry, we cab't open this presentation because we ran int a problem. To view or edit this presentation, open it is Microsoft PwerPoint."**

Everything works fine when I upload PDF. Uploading ppt files from 'Chrome Postman Extension' also works fine. So there must be some problem with my code here, but I can't figure it out.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->post(
   'https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files?access_token=' . $access_token,
   [
    'headers' => ['content-type' => 'multipart/form-data'],
    'body' => [
    'file' => fopen($path, 'r+')
    ]
   ]
  );
echo $response->json();
```

this code is using guzzle 4.0

------------------ Edit -----

I have also tried with newer versions of guzzle(6.*), but with that I am just unable to upload any file.

When using 'r' for fopen it gives.

**curl_setopt_array(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE***

and using any other mode gives

**Each stream must be readable**

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['debug'=>true]);
echo $client->post(
        'https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files?'.$token,
        [
            //'headers' => $headers,
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'file',
                    'contents' => fopen("J:/project data/MSL 4/Alcon MSL-Add-ons Jan 30.pdf", 'rb+'),
                ]
            ]
        ]

    );
```

Comment: Try to use `'rb+'` mode.

Comment: @cybersoft this lead me to new error 'Each stream must be readable'

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php - seems to be `r+b`...